# Infrared codes for Air Conditioners & Heat Pumps

Tags: automation, remote-control, home-automation

I need to enable an ESP32 to control any air conditioner / heat pump. The application requires autonomous remote control.

**Database**
I am aware of a few online databases that cover some but definitely not all models (i.e. irdb, which hasn't been maintained for years). This approach seems unreliable as there is little commercial momentum for maintenance.

**Universal Codes**
Back in the day, universal remotes were all the rage for a while. To use them, you needed to find the 4 digit code that corresponded to the manufacturer & product. Presumably all the detail you needed was then available direct from a database with 10,000? Entries?

**Learning**
The last option is to include an RX on the ESP32 and manually send it the code for On & Off. But this approach is limited to pretty much this. An aside - is it standard for controllers to have a different code for on & off - this is very relevant for my case where I will not have visual feedback of the current state.

With the stated goal above, to enable an ESP32 to control any type of Air Con / Heat Pump, I  need recommendations of libraries, resources or other that will enable me to reliably achieve my goal! Thanks in advance.